# Problema con registro de datos puerto serial

Tags: c#

Hola soy nuevo en programación espero me puedan ayudar

Tengo un detalle con mi código C# al registrar datos de un puerto serial no puedo hacer que se acumulen de manera vertical en un TextBox, ni en un datagridview, el codigo funciona con ReadExisting, pero al cambiarlo por ReadLine deja de registrar los valores y marca error al salir. Espero me puedan ayudar

aqui el codigo

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataIN = serialPort1.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
    }

private void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox5.Text += dataIN;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[1, 0].Value += dataIN;
                        
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para el grid intenga creando un data table y le vas asignando los datos y con ese mismo puedes usarlo para imprimirlos en el text area, o no se si con eso te refieres a vertical

Comment: El `Readline` va esperar que llegue un fin de línea y va a bloquear ese método. Lo tienes que hacer con ReadExisting para leer solo los bytes recibidos. Puedes ir acumulando en un buffer lo que recibes hasta que recibas el fin de línea. Ten en cuenta que un WriteLine al serial Port no necesariamente te va a llegar en bloque sino puedes recibirlo en n partes. Por eso es el evento DataReceived. Por otro lado puedes  verificar cuántos bytes llegaron utilizando `BytesToRead`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la información, pude solucionarlo, al parecer era un problema con la asignación de las columnas que tenia en el DatagridView

el código funciona ya, solo tiene el detalle que el primer dato que recibe aparece duplicado algunos valores o cortado, pero a partir del segundo dato recibido los escribe bien, intente poner un timeout pero no lo solución, alguna idea de que pueda estar pasando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]